# Comparing carbon dates in Laravel Framework

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How can I check if $expiresAt has actually expired, against the $now timestamp?

```
$expiresAt = Carbon::parse($tokenInstance->expires_at);
$now = Carbon::now();
```

Comment: Or you could just use `Carbon::parse(...)->isPast()`.

Answer (score 0):

This itself will work:

```
if($expiresAt < $now){
    echo 'Expired';
}else{
    echo 'No Expired';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but the Laravel Query Builder offers a more Eloquent solution:

$query ->whereDate('$expiresAt', '<', date('Y-m-d'));

more [here](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/)